# jQuery:animate conundrum

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, directory

I am having jQuery animation issues...

I have a footer with a hidden div on top of it.
When someone clicks a button near the header, the div should animate UP. Sort of like sliding up, like you're pulling a [manila folder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manila_folder) out of a drawer.  (Not the normal slide up where the bottom of the div slides up to the top.)

I found this piece of code that is kind of what I want, however, it's moving the baseline (footer).

```
.featureBox{width:182px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
    border:1px solid red;
}

$('.featureBox').hover(function()  {
    $(this).animate({top:'-320px', height:'540px'},"slow");
},
function() {
    $(this).animate({top:'0px', height:'150px'},"slow");
})
```

When mousing over the red div box, you'll see that the div below it pushes down.  How do I get it to just animate up or grow up? (He-he. Sorry. Just thought of mom yelling at me).

Comment: Other than thinking of my mom, I'm not clear on what you mean by "grow up". Do you mean stretch or move? (As in, the height stays the same, or the height stays the same and the bottom border doesn't move?)

Comment: can we see the html that this is working on? (that footer section and the hidden div)

Comment: Here... imagine this.  A bar chart.  You see the bars animate upwards on the chart (a la Flex).  How do you get a DIV to animate UP.  There's plenty of examples of animating down or left or right.  I haven't seen any examples on how to keep the base of a DIV at the same level and have the top of the DIV rise.

Comment: Try this URL:

http://jsbin.com/etafu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsbin.com/onima) is a page working the way I think you want.  I think the main problem was the the expanding div needs to be inside a div that has a height.  [Here](http://jsbin.com/ogaje) is a page with the expaning div covering other content when it expands.

Check out the code for the [Wordpress Sexybookmarks plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/sexybookmarks/screenshots/) for a good example of this kind of trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your fix is one of these two things:

1. Change position:relative to position:absolute
2. You don't want to actually move .featureBox but rather another element inside of .featureBox (probably a DIV)